# Asp.Net MVC - JavaScript events for elements rendered using knockout are not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm loading a PartialView in to the `_Layout.cshtml` using `@await Html.PartialAsync('')` that has a `knockout template binding` generated menu.

But the sub menus are not populating. If I manually executed the `JS` event in browser consol, it works.

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/html" id="treeItem">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: Name"></a>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeItem', foreach: SubCategory }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>
<script>    
    viewModel = {
        lookupCollection: ko.observableArray()
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/Category",
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(data).each(function (index, element) {
                viewModel.lookupCollection.push(element);            
            });
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }).error(function (ex) {
            alert("Error");
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="block_content">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeItem', foreach: lookupCollection }"></ul>
</div>
```

`main.js` -- one (of many) function for the menu

```
$('#categories_block_left.simple ul li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var submenuWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if($('.sidebar').hasClass('right-column')) {
        $(this).hover().find('ul').first().css({'width': submenuWidth, 'right': +submenuWidth}).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hover().find('ul').first().css({'width': submenuWidth, 'right': -submenuWidth}).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Any code? How exactly your menu partial view looks like? Provide any qualification? There can be 100500 reasons why it doesn't work.

Comment: You might need to delegate the items in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing

```
$('#categories_block_left.simple ul li').on('mouseenter', function() {
```

to

```
$('#categories_block_left.simple ').on('mouseenter','ul li', function() {
```